# laravel 5.4 chrome for android not showing validation errors

Tags: android, laravel, google-chrome, validation, flash

I have a website working perfectly on desktop, however, google chrome is not showing validation error messages or flash info.

I tried other navigators like html source code viewer: worked perfectly

on chrome for desktop, everything is ok

when I serve my project from my computer and access it throgh wifi, it works perfectly

My server is running nginx on linux debian

The problem is, this only happens on my signin/signup page, other pages are showing errors and flash messages perfectly even on chrome for android

here is my view:

```
    <h3>Welcome back</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{         route('auth.signin') }}">
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="email" class="control-label"         id="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control"         id="email">
                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('email')         }}</span>
                    @endif              
                </div>
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-        error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="password" class="control-        label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-        control" id="password">
                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors-        >first('password') }}</span>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign         in</button>
                    <a style="padding-left: 10px;" href="{{         route('auth.forgot') }}">Frogot your password?</a>
                </div>          
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">          
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
```

(please don't mind the spaces in the code, I don't have these in my page)

inside my controller, I have this:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);
```

and I show flash messages this way:

```
    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Incorrect sign in information.');
```

can you please help me out? this is really weird and frustrating

thank you

Answer (score -1):

Haser!

I have the same problem on the test server, but the production is ok.
Having studied all the circumstances, I am inclined to believe that in my case the problem lies in the absence of https on the test server.

My logic is this: mobile chrome sees the password entry field and sees that there is no certificate. These two circumstances come to non-standard behavior. Indirectly, I managed to confirm my theory by studying the password change page, there is the same situation with the absence of errors.

This behavior is observed only in mobile chrome on android!

Comment: Maybe use the comment function. The Answer function is only for "solutions"!

Comment: I have too little karma to add a comment to someone else’s question / answer. As follows from my answer, try installing the HTTPS certificate on your server. Or try to reproduce the problem on the server where you installed the certificate.